# Azure DataLake with DVC

Tags: azure-data-lake, service-principal, dvc

We are thinking to use DVC for versioning input data for DataScience project.
my data resides in Azure DataLake Gen1.

how do i configure DVC to push data to Azure DataLake using Service Principal?
i want DVC to store cache and data into Azure DataLake instead on local disk.

Comment: dvc officially only supports regular azure blob storage. AFAIK Gen1 DataLake should be accessible by the same interface, so configuring a regular azure remote for dvc should work. E.g.
```
    $ dvc remote add myremote azure://my-container-name/path
    $ dvc remote modify myremote connection_string my-connection-string
```
Please try it out.